# Is adding routes thread-safe in Spark framework?

Tags: java, multithreading, spark-java

The SimpleRouteMatcher stores added routes in an ArrayList.

```
public SimpleRouteMatcher() {
    routes = new ArrayList<RouteEntry>();
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any synchronization surrounding the access of these routes. Since they are accessed from a separate server thread, are updates to the list of routes guaranteed to be visible?

Answer (score 1):

You answered the question yourself - [it seems it is not](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/master/src/main/java/spark/route/Routes.java). Probably, there was the assumption: adding routes will only happen in the main thread on application startup, from the main method, so this might be implemented non-thread safe on purpose.

If you need to modify routes safely from multiple threads, you can create wrapper methods for these operations which are `synchronized`.

In my opinion, this operation should have been thread safe out-of-the-box.